Romantic comedy about a college student and a rich girl
I'm looking for a movie about a college student meeting a girl. He goes out with her but she gets drunk and passes out at the train station. He brings her home with a cab and discovers she is quite rich.
At the end of the movie the girl is somewhere else for a long time. But they decided if it was true love they would meet up at a certain spot. Something with a tree....
Can't remember most of the movie and can't seem to find which movie it was.

In which year did you watch this movie? How old do you think it was?

It should be My Sassy Girl.

My Sassy Girl is the tale of the first and last time Charlie Bello falls in love. From their initial meeting, trouble is the name of the game. Imagine an amorphous mass of dating disasters and you get an idea of the relationship between the young couple. Some mysterious force with the strength of gravity between two planets must be at play between Charlie and Jordan as the relationship truly makes no sense on the surface. Everything seems pitted against the two of them. Things suddenly come to a halt when the two write letters confessing their love for each other. Agreeing to meet a year later to read the love letters together, Charlie and Jordan go their separate ways. - IMDb

I watched this film and it meets all the specified details. She was a drunk when they met at some train station, before separating their ways, they buried confession letter under tree. Full synopsis is present on Wikipedia in above mentioned link.

That's the one I was looking for. Thank you.
